# Dado un valor de y, cuantos pares de números enteros positivos (A,B) son soluciones de A + 2*np.sqrt(A*B) + B = Y? Python

Tags: python

No se como resolver un ejercicio (python), en el que dado un valor de "y"(y=2001) se me pide calcular cuantos pares de números enteros positivos (A,B) son soluciones de la ecuación: [A + 2*np.sqrt(A*B) + B = Y], usando bucles for y sentencias de control if, mostrando por pantalla la cantidad de parejas de A,B. Además si el valor de A,B coincide, la variable acumulativa solo aumenta su valor en 1, mientras que si son distintos a la variable acumulativa se le suma 2. A continuación dejo el fragmento de código que hasta ahora llevo planteado, por si fuese útil.

Gracias por adelantado.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import *

Y=20001

for A in Y:
   if(A and B) >= 0:
        A + 2np.sqrt(A*B) + B = Y
```

Comment: Vas muy bien, como tú dices... Crea una nueva variable donde acumular los datos. Creo que al hacer A + 2np.sqrt(A*B) + B = Y  te estás confundiendo ya que estás haciendo una `asignación` y lo que tu estás buscando es hacer una `comparación`. Con la comparación (operador `==`) puedes luego utilizar un `if` para poder incrementar el valor de tu variable acumulativa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una solución:

```
import math

def calc_pares(y):
    pares = []
    for a in range(1, y):
        for b in range(a, y):
            value = a+2*math.sqrt(a*b)+b
            if value == y:
              pares.append((a, b))
    return pares
```

La función recibe un entero y retorna la lista de pares positivos que cumplen la ecuación señalada.

La lista se obtiene con un doble `for` sobre el entero recibido. El `for` más externo recorre todos los enteros entre 1 y el valor recibido. El `for` más interno recorre solo los enteros superiores; así sólo se generan pares (a, b), donde a <= b. Esto evita considerar el mismo para dos veces (a, b) y (b, a).

Si el valor calculado coincide con el valor recibido, se agrega el par a la lista de salida.

**Comprobación**

```
for i in range(1, 25):
    print(i, calc_pares(i))
```

produce:

```
1 []
2 []
3 []
4 [(1, 1)]
5 []
6 []
7 []
8 [(2, 2)]
9 [(1, 4)]
10 []
11 []
12 [(3, 3)]
13 []
14 []
15 []
16 [(1, 9), (4, 4)]
17 []
18 [(2, 8)]
19 []
20 [(5, 5)]
21 []
22 []
23 []
24 [(6, 6)]
```

Edición

La versión pitonesca en una línea sería:

```
pares = [(a, b) for a in range(1, y) for b in range(a, y) if a+2*math.sqrt(a*b)+b == y]
```

con `y` siendo el valor para el cual se quiere calcular.

Comment: Gracias, me ha sido de gran ayuda.